# Overflow not being applied

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, tailwind-css

I am working on a portfolio website with ReactJS + TailwindCSS.
Part of it is a section called 'About Me' where I have longer text. This longer text fits nicely as long as the text is not 'too long', then it reaches out of its parent `div`.

[image]

You can see similar effect on my Article Cards. I want them to stay the same size, nevertheless the amount of text in the `footer`.

This is my React Component where I render the the Article Cards:

```
function MainComponent() {
  return (
    <div className="container my-12 mx-auto px-4 md:px-12">
      <div className="flex flex-wrap -mx-1 lg:-mx-4">
        <ProjectComponent
          projectName="Lorem Ipsum 1"
          projectDescription="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In et nisl nulla. Sed tincidunt diam sit amet dictum posuere. Ut diam velit, rhoncus nec ligula vel, hendrerit hendrerit dui. Nunc eget augue faucibus, interdum diam condimentum, ullamcorper ex. Aenean ultricies urna at posuere pharetra. Nunc facilisis velit vitae ornare pretium. Suspendisse egestas sem eu facilisis tempor. Nullam ac malesuada libero. Mauris vulputate viverra mi, ac rutrum ante suscipit in. Donec vitae aliquet dolor. Aenean malesuada nec enim in tempus."
          projectImage={TEST_IMAGE_URL}
          projectUrl="someurl"
        />
        <ProjectComponent
          projectName="Lorem Ipsum 2"
          projectDescription={TEST_ABOUT_ME}
          projectImage={TEST_IMAGE_URL}
          projectUrl="someurl"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is my Header Component (the About Me part that you can see overflow)

```
function HeaderComponent() {
  return (
    <div className="max-w-full h-1/5 rounded-sm shadow-lg flex flex-row">
      <img src={profile} alt="Profile" className="flex-none w-64 p-2" />
      <div className="flex-grow min-h-full">
        <h1 className="text-lg text-white mt-10 font-sans">My Name</h1>
        <p className="text-sm text-white mt-5 font-sans">{TEST_ABOUT_ME}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="flex-none w-64"></div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Project Component that displays the Article Cards is wrapped in following DIV:

```
<div
  className={`my-1 px-1 w-full md:w-1/2 lg:my-4 lg:px-4 lg:w-1/3 transform transition-all duration-1000 ease-out scale-${scale}`}
></div>
```

I am pretty sure that it is something with my Flexbox, I am still quite new with this, but I couldn't figure out how to make my texts not to overflow in Y axis.

Comment: How are your css classes defined?

Comment: @Dario all CSS classes are written inline as you can see above. I am using TailwindCSS for this.

Comment: Did you try max-height and overflow: auto?

Comment: @BZCn I tried playing around with it. I apply it to the parent elemnt (the Flex one) and I can see in the Inspect that the size changed, but the Article cards still remain the same height, ingnoring my max-h-full , which should set the elements max height to the parent's height.

Comment: @BZC OK, for text is easier so I managed to get it to work with how you said to set heigh to the parent element and then the child elmeent has max-height set. However, I cannot figure out how to deal with my Grid :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `h-#` + `max-h-#` + `overflow-auto` for this. Checkout a [working example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ldC7d9UxS6).

```
<div class="flex gap-x-8">
  <div class="flex flex-1 flex-col">
    <div class="h-48 bg-gray-100"></div>
    <div class="h-48 max-h-48 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto bg-blue-200">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde officiis qui rerum possimus fugit enim quos illo nostrum. Maxime soluta nostrum voluptas iusto autem, odit tenetur facere reprehenderit molestiae facilis?
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-1 flex-col">
   <div class="h-48 bg-gray-100"></div>
   <div class="h-48 max-h-48 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto bg-blue-200">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente error, vel expedita odio, nobis magni tempore optio voluptas deleniti eum nemo corrupti animi provident ipsa deserunt voluptatem sint? Est, quo.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo quidem recusandae officiis quaerat adipisci corrupti ab, dolorem, ipsum repudiandae quam asperiores esse iusto veniam cupiditate magnam! Aspernatur velit quae vero!
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam hic magnam perspiciatis eligendi perferendis temporibus, provident nihil iste libero aliquam natus mollitia maiores. Consequuntur voluptatum repudiandae similique quo nulla accusantium!
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This indeed answers my question and I will accept it as answer! Thanks. Now I have to figure out, how to prevent this auto-scaling that it does to my cards. I want them to of fixed width too.. but it seems it tries to squish them within the parent div. I wouldn't mind if it is scrollable

Comment: In that case I would suggest to use `grid`.

Comment: Thanks. I am curious about the difference between flexbox and grid? Is it exactly the fact that childs in flex can 'change size dynamically' while in grid they are always fixed sized?

Comment: Checkout this video from Kevin Powell [Floats, Flexbox, Grid? The progression of CSS layouts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7gqJkdc5dM)